# Livewire datatable failed to install in laravel 10

Tags: laravel-livewire, laravel-10

I'm trying to install livewire datatable in my laravel 10 project but it seems like there is a dependecies conflicts. After running the installation command:

```
composer require mediconesystems/livewire-datatables
```

The following result is what i got

[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHRTi.png)

I've tried to search for the way out but the only solution i've found is to downgrade laravel 10 to laravel 9 [here is the link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/livewire/livewire-datatable-shows-compatibility-issues-in-laravel-10)

Is there another way i can do rather than downgrading to laravel 9?

Answer (score 0):

The package requires `reedware/laravel-relation-joins` either `^2.4` or `^3.0` ([on Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/mediconesystems/livewire-datatables)). However, `2.4` only supports up to Laravel 8, and `3.0` up to Laravel 9. You need it at `4.0` for Laravel 10, but while `mediconesystems/livewire-datatables` supposedly supports Laravel 10, it doesn't work with `reedware/laravel-relation-joins` version `4.0`. You might try manually installing version `4.0`, but chances are it still won't work.

If you don't want to downgrade (makes sense), all you can do is wait until the package is updated. It doesn't like a shocking package, however, so perhaps it's better to just make your own solution.

Comment: Thanks @Yinci for the response, i've tried to manually install version 4.0 but as you've said it still doesn't work. I've decided to downgrade to laravel version 9 and it works